# Gitlab curl script fail due to self signed certificate error

Tags: bash, ssl, curl, gitlab, jobs

So I am trying to hit an endpoint with the following in manual Gitlab job.

```
test-manual-job:
  stage: demo-test
  when: manual
  variables:
    QNAME: "${QNAME}"
  script:
    - echo "Hello world. User input is ${QNAME}"
    - curl -X GET -H 'Accept:application/json' "https://main-demo-services.nr.dflop-swf-prod.bee.ds.local/services/dataUser/reloadStatus/" --ssl-no-revoke
```

I successfuly hit my endpoint in the command prompt, but once i try to run this manual job in Gitlab, I get the following error:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: "Fix"? Setup a proper certificate or add it to your trusted certificates. "Workaround" by ignoring the warning

Comment: [How to trust self-signed certificate in cURL command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/451207/74329)